# Trying to format date to save worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, date

I am looking to save an individual worksheet from a workbook with today's date in the filename. ex. (c:\HotDogS\sales\Daily_12_04_16.xslx)

The problem I am encountering is getting the date to show right in the filename.
I have 1 cell that has the simple formula of `=TODAY()`. The cell is formatted for mm/dd/yy.

The formula I am trying to use to save the date for the sheet is:
`=left(B3,2)&"_"&mid(B3,4,2)&"_"&right(B3,2)`

So I am expecting a date of 12/04/16 to come out as 12_04_16, but I am getting is, 42_08_08.

Can somebody shed some light on this??

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `TODAY` is 4 December 2016, i.e. serial day number 42708, your formula is:

```
=left(B3,2)&"_"&mid(B3,4,2)&"_"&right(B3,2)
```

`Left(B3,2)` is `42`.  `Mid(B3,4,2)` is `08`.  `Right(B3,2)` is `08`.

So your final result is `42_08_08`.

You probably want to use (as an Excel formula):

```
=TEXT(B3,"mm\_dd\_yy")
```

Or in VBA you could use

```
Format(Range("B3").Value, "mm_dd_yy")
```

---

Excel stores dates as the number of days (and fractions of a day) since 0 January 1900.  Therefore

- 1 January 1900 is day 1
- 31 January 1900 is day 31
- 1 February 1900 is day 32
- 29 February 1900 (even though it doesn't exist - but the bug has been maintained for backward compatibility) is day 60
- 1 January 1901 is day 367
- 4 December 2016 is day 42708
- NOW() is day 42709.328 (it's about 7:52am on 5 December 2016 at the moment)

Comment: If you don't mind the additional question, how is the date serial calculated?

Answer (score 1):

Referencing a cell formatted as date returns the underlying date serial number.

To get a date formatted as you want use

```
=TEXT(B3,"dd\_mm\_yy")
```